# Text not visible when padding added to OutlinedTextField in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When I try to place a OutlinedTextField in the scaffold of Jetpack compose with padding added , the typed text in the outlinedTextField is not visible. My code for Scaffold is as below:

```
Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = {
                Row(
                   verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                  horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp)
                ) {
                    Text(text = title)
                    if (canShowSearchBar) {
                       
                            OutlinedTextField(
                                value = searchText,
                                onValueChange = { newText ->
                                    searchText = newText
                                },
                                modifier = Modifier
                                    .height(60.dp)
                                    .padding(top = 5.dp, bottom = 5.dp)
                                    .background(Color.White)
                                    .weight(1f),
                                textStyle = TextStyle(color = Color.Black, fontSize = 16.sp),
                                singleLine = true,
                                keyboardActions = KeyboardActions(
                                    onDone = {
                                        // Handle search action here
                                    }
                                ),
                                keyboardOptions = KeyboardOptions.Default.copy(
                                    imeAction = ImeAction.Done
                                )
                            )




                    }
                }

            },
            actions = {

                if (canShowCart) {
                    Box(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .width(50.dp)
                            .height(50.dp)
                            .clickable { onCartClick() },
                        //.background(Color.Magenta),
                        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    ) {
                        if (cartItemCount > 0) {
                            Badge(
                                content = { Text(text = cartItemCount.toString()) },
                                modifier = Modifier.align(
                                    Alignment.TopStart
                                )
                            )
                        }
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center)
                        )
                    }
                }
                if (canShowLogout) {
                    IconButton(onClick = onLogoutClick) {
                        Icon(Icons.Default.ExitToApp, contentDescription = null)
                    }
                }
            }
        )
    },
   
) {
    content()
```

Comment: Copying your code here I see that the text is partially hidden by the padding on the outlined text field. When I removed this from the modifier, all the text was visible

Comment: Can't reproduce with the material3 components.